# Can not create a docker machine on wsl2 virtualbox

Tags: docker

I'm using wsl2 to test some docker commands. I installed virtualbox 7.0 on wy win11 host machine.As I think it will be used to contol created node when I type the command : docek-machine create --driver virtualbox node.
The error is showing :

```
  WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
             Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
             headers, most likely linux-headers-standard.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 6.1.38_Ubuntu
(C) 2005-2022 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.
```

Another error also appear :

```
Error with pre-create check: "We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is \"WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.\\n\\t Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate\\n\\t headers, most likely linux-headers-standard.\\n\\n\\t You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\\n6.1.38_Ubuntur153438\". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org"
```

when I try to install the virtual box-dmks by typing :

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) 

it shows me this error : 
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
```

How can I fix this issue?.I really need your help ,I'm blocked since 3 hours.